# How to split a string into individual characters where each new character is added into an array as a json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, split

I have an array of json objects where each object has permanent key 'type' and other keys depending on the type. It looks like so:

```
theArray = [
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "= SUM("
    },
    {
        "type": "formula",
        "attrs": {
            "id": 20,
            "data": "Cost",
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": ",,"
    }
]
```

I've filtered all items where "type": "text" like so:

```
this.theArray.filter(a=>a.type === 'text'))
```

I am attempting to split each object where type === 'text' so that every character inside of the text key is an item in this.theArray.

So in this. theArray above where "type": "text" I want to split it into the following:

```
theArray = [
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "="
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": " "
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "S"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "U"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "M"
    },
    {
        "type": "formula",
        "attrs": {
            "id": 20,
            "data": "Cost",
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": ","
    }
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": ","
    },
]
```

Where the first object with type text is split **in order of character** so that each =, ,S,U,M,( is added as a new item in the array with "type": "text" and text: that item.

I know that to split a string separately I need to use .split('')

However here is what I have so far, it doesn't work (I just get the original json object of *= SUM(*) and I'm unsure of how to go further. Would anyone know of a way to edit the first array to show the second?

```
if(theArray.filter(a=>a.type === 'text')) {
    theArray.map(a=>a.text).forEach(element => {
        element.split('')
        theArray.push({type:"text", text: element})
    })
}
```

Comment: If you're not using the return value of the callback function you should use `forEach()`, not `map()`.

Comment: You shouldn't add to the array that you're mapping over. Put the result in a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) allowing you to return an array of new objects for the `text` objects and flatten them out in the return. Here using [spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to split the strings into an array of characters before mapping them to individual objects.

```js
const theArray = [
  {
    "type": "text",
    "text": "= SUM("
  },
  {
    "type": "formula",
    "attrs": {
      "id": 20,
      "data": "Cost",
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "text": ",,"
  }
]

const result = theArray.flatMap(o => {
  if (o.type === 'text') {
    return [...o.text].map(char => ({ type: o.type, text: char }));
  }
  return o;
})

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a single map with a conditional for `el.type === 'text'`:

```js
const theArray = [
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "= SUM("
    },
    {
        "type": "formula",
        "attrs": {
            "id": 20,
            "data": "Cost",
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": ",,"
    }
]

console.log(
    theArray
      .flatMap((el) => el.type === 'text' ? el.text.split('').map((char) => ({ type: 'text', text: char })) : el)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#:%7E:text=prototype.-,flatMap(),calling%20those%20two%20methods%20separately.) here

one liner

```
const result = theArray.flatMap((o) =>
  o.type === "text"
    ? o.text.split("").map((s) => ({ type: o.type, text: s }))
    : o
);
```

```js
const theArray = [
  {
    type: "text",
    text: "= SUM(",
  },
  {
    type: "formula",
    attrs: {
      id: 20,
      data: "Cost",
    },
  },
  {
    type: "text",
    text: ",,",
  },
];

const result = theArray.flatMap((o) => {
  if (o.type === "text") {
    return o.text.split("").map((s) => ({ type: o.type, text: s }));
  }

  return o;
});
console.log(result);
```